# spring boot Enterprise application with eureka and zuul

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am in charge of designing a new enterprise application that should handle tons of clients and should be completely fault free.
In order to to that I'm thinking about implementing different microservices that are going to be replicated so eureka server / client solution is perfect for this.
Then since the eureka server could be the single point of failure I found that is possible to have it replicated in multiple instances and it is perfect.
In order to not expose every service I'm going to put as a gateway zuul that will use the eureka server in order to find the perfect instance of the backend serivice that will handle the requests.
Since now zuul is the single point of faiulre I found that it is possible to replicate also this component so if one of them fails I still have the others.

At this point I need to find the way to create a load balancer between the client application (android and ios app) and the zuul stack but a server side load balancer will be the single point of failure so it is useless.
I would like to ask if there is a way to make our tons of clients connect to an healty instance of zuul application without having any single point of failure. Maybe by implementing ribbon on the mobile application that will choose a proper healty instance of zuul.
Unfortunatly everything will be deployed on a "private" cluster so I can not use amazon elastic load balancer or any other different propietary solution
Thanks